# Как использовать названия из 2х слов в sql workbench

Tags: sql, select

```
select Тип собственности from предприятие;
```

Тип собственности - название столбца.

Comment: `select "Тип собственности" from предприятие; `

Comment: Тогда вывод - колонка Тип собственности и все строки тоже теперь Тип собственности. Я перепробовал все ' " | { [ не так все просто(

Comment: Тогда дайте скрипт, как вы таблицу создаёте и какую базу используете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901453/5045688

Comment: `select \`Тип собственности\` ...`

Comment: если это чисто по sql запрос, то можно выбрать select [Тип собственности] from предприятие;